# get set operators from dict on python

Tags: python, dictionary, set, logical-operators

If I have two or more sets, and a string that describe de operation that must be done between them, like 'and', 'or', 'xor', it can be obviously get done like this:

```
if string == 'and': 
    return set1.intersection(set2)
elif string == 'or'
    return set1 | set2
```

and so on. What if I want to do it with a dictionary?
I have something like this:

```
dictionary = {'and': set.intersection, 'or': set.union}
return set1.dictionary[string](set2)
```

And also tried

```
operation = dictionary.get(string)
return set1.operation(set2)
```

But none worked. How can I achieve the same result that I get through ifs but with a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set.itersection()`, `set.union()`, etc. as *static methods*, passing multiple sets to them:

```
>>> ops = {'and': set.intersection, 'or': set.union}
>>> set1 = {1, 2, 3}
>>> set2 = {3, 4, 5}
>>> ops['and'](set1, set2)
{3}
>>> ops['or'](set1, set2)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Alternatively, you could map operations to method names and use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
>>> ops = {'and': 'intersection', 'or': 'union'}
>>> getattr(set1, ops['and'])(set2)
{3}
>>> getattr(set1, ops['or'])(set2)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: that's right. What if I must also have the set.difference operator? then it needs two arguments but they won't be interchangeable.

Comment: Can you clarify? If you pass the sets in the same order, then  `set.difference` should work as well. You can also use `gettatr()` on a set object (see the update).

Comment: You are right. I was confused since, implemented directly, the method is written `set1.difference(set2)`0 so I thought `set.difference(set1, set2)` would be like `set() - set1 - set2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `attrgetter`

```
from operator import attrgetter

set_methods = {"and": attrgetter("intersection"), 'or': attrgetter("union")}
```

Call it like: `set_methods[method_string](set1)(set2)`.